# JavaScript update textarea freezes Chrome, but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, textarea

On a page there is an upload button that allows a user to upload a text file and the file contents are input into a textarea box on the same page.  When testing with a 3MB text file using this function in Firefox, it works fine.  But when using with Chrome, the browser locks up and the animation loader freezes for a bit and then the page becomes responsive again.  Here is the relevant js code:

```
function getFile(event) {
  const input = event.target
  if ('files' in input && input.files.length > 0) {
    placeFileContent(document.getElementById('corpus'), input.files[0]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#characters').text($('#corpus').val().length.toLocaleString());
      $('#words').text($('#corpus').val().trim().split(/\s+/).length.toLocaleString());
    }, 10);
  }
}

function placeFileContent(target, file) {
  readFileContent(file).then(content => {
    target.value = content;
  }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}

function readFileContent(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.onload = event => resolve(event.target.result)
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error)
    reader.readAsText(file)
  })
};
```

The upload button code:

```
$('#uploadCorpus').on('change', function(event) {
  $("#corpus").LoadingOverlay("show");
  setTimeout(function() {
    getFile(event);
  }, 1000);
  $("#corpus").LoadingOverlay("hide", true);
})
```

I removed the animation, abd the counting of words/characters and the problem still persists.  Using Chrome dev tools, the lag is in the layout action afte the text has been read.  When I just put the content into a var, there is no lag in the browser.  Instead of updating the textarea value, is there some other way of updating without locking the UI?  The user will edit the file before submitting to DB.

I disabled spellcheck, autocomplete, etc.

Comment: Putting 3MB in a `textarea`? I guess the browser just takes some time to do all the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue in Chrome even when pasting large text. I mitigated it by checking file size and if over x upload without viewing text in browser.

```
var size = document.getElementById('uploadCorpus').files[0].size;
```