# Loading the large text into text area takes a lot of time in the browser and browser crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, textarea, loading

I tried checking out a few answers but most of them were related to either list or table and one answer I found was related to `ace.js` which I could not understand completely so posting the same.

I have a project in `Node.js` which will create the `XML` content dynamically based on the user input and the final output of the created XML can be very large as they can create 1000's of XML. After the creation, the XML content will be returned to `AngularJS` where I am populating the `Textarea` with the returned content.

The XML content is created pretty quickly and returned to `AngularJS` but I observe that after getting the response the loading of the XML content to `textarea` is taking a lot of time. I wanted to know is there any method using which I can fasten the process.

My HTML file with the text area field `index.html`:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="xmldata" ng-model="xmldata" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

My AngularJS HTTP request which will return the XML content:

```
$http({
    url: "/XMLCreatir",
    method: "POST",
    data: data
}).success(function(response) {
    console.log("RECEIEVED XML");
    $scope.xmldata  =   response;
});
```

I can observe that the `RECEIVED XML` is displayed pretty quickly but the `Textarea` will not load the content and also most of the time browser crashes.

- As the XML content is created at once I do not want to split it up into small chunks and concatenate again. I am hoping there is some better workaround for this.
- I tried the solution mentioned here but for some reason, nothing was changed for me:
  [Dynamically displaying large amounts of text by partially displaying data in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689920/dynamically-displaying-large-amounts-of-text-by-partially-displaying-data-in-tex)

Can someone please help me with this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Large text in TextArea freezes computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600398/large-text-in-textarea-freezes-computer)

Comment: @OfirD Thanks for the response. No actually that does not answer completely. I am using the `Chrome` browser and as you can see from my code, some of the things mentioned in that answer I have incorporated already in my application such as `autocomplete`, ``spellcheck` etc. I am guessing there should be some JS library or some workaround to show this data. Thanks and looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: There's no way around it. Large text means long rendering. See also [JavaScript update textarea freezes Chrome, but not Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675786/javascript-update-textarea-freezes-chrome-but-not-firefox). You can limit the length, though, see this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533053/textarea-character-limit).

Comment: Ok but if you check this answer they are trying to use some JS library to make it faster https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689920/dynamically-displaying-large-amounts-of-text-by-partially-displaying-data-in-tex So I guess there are some libraries or some other approach which can make it a bit faster.

Comment: *Making it a bit faster* - make sure you understand what's that *"it"*. If it is the user experience, then absolutely, if lazy loading (which is what that answer attempts) fits you, go ahead and implement it as suggested, it's definitely another mitigation you can use to allow good user experience. However, if you're expecting to keep having a large text inside the textarea, then expect long rendering (and crashing).